# Change indexed character of string

Tags: c#, char

Im working on a program that changes a specified character, if its uppercase, it will change it to lowercase and vice versa.

I have written a piece of code that in theory should work. I have also written it with a foreach(char c in x) method but that wont work wither. Any tips?

Expected output **teSTSTring**
Given output **TEststRING**

```
            string x = "TEststRING";

            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                if (char.IsUpper(x[i]))
                {
                    char.ToLower(x[i]);
                }
                if (char.IsLower(x[i]))
                {
                    char.ToUpper(x[i]);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: `char.ToLower()` and `char.ToUpper()` both return the lowercase/uppercase equivalent, they do not change the value provided (`x[i]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with StringBuilder

```cs
string x = "TEststRING";
car sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (car c in x)
{
    if (char.IsUpper(c))
    {
        sb.Append(char.ToLower(c));
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(char.ToUpper(c));
    }    
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly!
Im gonna have to do some more digging into why my method did not work, might have something to do with it not being able to change the indexed character of the string.

Comment: @21sili your method did not work because you executed the ToLower en ToUpper function, but did not use the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing the input string. I would suggest you use the below code.

It will handle the cases where you have characters other than alphabets as well.

```
string output = new string(x.Select(c => char.IsLetter(c) ? (char.IsUpper(c) ? char.ToLower(c) : char.ToUpper(c)) : c).ToArray());
```

Comment: That work very well, and i find that method of creating a new string with conditions new to me, does it have a name by any chance?

Comment: @21sili its constructor

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to my `foreach` version. This alternative will use `Linq` like vivek nuna's answer. Note that Linq is a powerful part of C#, while you should dig it, it is quite advanced. Here is my version of it:

```cs
char SwitchCase(char c) => char.IsUpper(c) ? char.ToLower(c) : char.ToUpper(c);
        
var x = "TEststRING(1)";
var output = string.Concat(x.Select(SwitchCase));
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Changes include:

- Use [`string.Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=net-7.0) to, well, concat the `IEnumerable` into a `string` instead of using `ToArray()` with `new string()`
- Remove the `char.IsLetter` check, `ToUpper` already handles it.
- Create a `SwitchCase` function to name the logic

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sct9Us)